# How to add event listeners using a for loop to dynamically generated buttons

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a page w/ dynamically generated buttons and i'm trying  to add event listeneners to them using a for loop. 
I'm not sure why my code is not working as it refers the each button via it's ID and uses dot notation to add the event listener.  There is some commenting in the code to help clarify.

Here is abbreviated markup showing the buttons *only*

```
<button class="btnRollDice" id="btnRollDiceP1">Roll Dice!</button>
<button class="btnRollDice" id="btnRollDiceP2">Roll Dice!</button>
<button class="btnRollDice" id="btnRollDiceP3">Roll Dice!</button>
```

Here is the js

```
rollDiceBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btnRollDice');//returns a HTML collection

function addEventListeners(){
    console.log(rollDiceBtns);
    for(i=0;i<rollDiceBtns.length;i++){
        console.log(rollDiceBtns[i].id); //THIS WORKS, 
        rollDiceBtns[i].id.addEventListener('click', rollDice, false); //THIS DOES NOT
    }
}
```

How would this be done using a for loop? to dynamically generated buttons?

Comment: remove `.id.` on that last line perhaps? You don't add an even tlistener to a string.

Answer (score 1):

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is a method you find on elements.

`rollDiceBtns[i]` is an element.

`rollDiceBtns[i].id` is a string.

Remove `.id`.