# Use a for loop to add a variable to an instance name with javascript/canvas

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, instance, addeventlistener

Can I use a for loop with an instance on addEventListener? For example I have the following working correctly with buttons called 'highlightbtn_1' through to 'highlightbtn_5':

```
this.highlightbtn_1.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
this.highlightbtn_2.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
this.highlightbtn_3.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
this.highlightbtn_4.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
this.highlightbtn_5.addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
```

Is is possible to instead use a for loop within the button instances to cycle through them, rather than adding individual EventListeners for each button? Similar to this:

```
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
      this.highlightbtn_[+i].addEventListener("click", onClick.bind(this));
      //Some onClick function
    }
```

I did find a [similar topic answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824313/how-to-add-event-listeners-using-a-for-loop-to-dynamically-generated-buttons), but I couldn't get it to work.Thank you in advance for any input at all!

Comment: Why isn't `highlightbtns` an array? That would make everything much simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - I'm not sure where to start with that but I appreciate the answer and can look into it more from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object property can be accessed two ways:

- `obj.propertyName`
- `obj['propertyName']`

second way you can use an expression.

So, you can to use `this['highlightbtn_'+i]`

*Or refactor them to be an array.*

*Or add them some CSS class and add common event listener.*

Comment: Thanks @vp_arth 'this['highlightbtn_'+i]' is what I was looking for and it works great. I am also curious to try an array, but for now this solves my issue.